# Perl iterating through each line in a file and and appending to the end of each line in another file - follow up

Tags: perl, filehandle

I have a follow up question regarding an ealier post. 
The post in question is: 
[Perl iterating through each line in a file and appending to the end of each line in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729519/perl-iterating-through-each-line-in-a-file-and-and-appending-to-the-end-of-each)

I used:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $animals, '<', 'File1.txt' or die "Can't open animals: $!";
open my $payloads, '<', 'File2.txt' or die "Can't open payloads: $!";

my @payloads = <$payloads>;   #each line of the file into an array
close $payloads or die "Can't close payloads: $!";

while (my $line = <$animals>) {
    chomp $line;
    print $line.$_ foreach (@payloads);
}
close $animals or die "Can't close animals: $!";
```

This works fine for files that look like this:

```
file 1:     file 2:
line1       lineA
line2       lineB
line3       lineC
```

but not for files that look like this:

```
<01 line1
<02 line2
```

So what I want to do is the following:

```
file 1:              file 2:
<01 line1            <AA lineAA
<02 line2            <AB lineAB
```

should become:

```
file 3:
<01_AA line1lineAA
<01_AB line1lineAB
<02_AA line2lineAA
<02_AB line2lineAB
```

I have tried to solve it by splitting the strings on the tab using while loops in while loops (see below), but I cannot get it to work.

my script:

```
#!C:/perl64/bin/perl.exe

use warnings;
use strict;


open my $file1, '<', 'file1.fasta' or die "Can't open file1: $!";
open my $file2, '<', 'file2.fasta' or die "Can't open file2:     $!";
open(OUT, '>', 'file3.fasta') or die "Cannot write $!";



while (<$file2>)
{
    chomp;
    my ($F2_Id, @SF2_seq) = split (/\t/, $_);

     while (<$file1>)
        {
            chomp;
            my ($F1_Id, @F1_seq) = split (/\t/, $_);
            foreach my $seq (@F1_seq)
                {
                    print OUT $F1_Id,"_",$F2_Id,"\t",$seq.$_ foreach (@F2_seq),"\n";
                }
            close;
        }
}
```

I started with perl just recently so I can imagine that there are a lot of faults in the script.

I'm sorry for the really long post, but I would appriciate any help.

Comment: Do all lines look like  `<01 line1 ` or is it just some of them?

Comment: Yes all lines look like <01 line1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the id and seq of the first file in an array of arrays.

You also have to replace the `<` in the second file with `_`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $LEFT,  '<', 'file1.fasta' or die "Can't open file1: $!";
open my $RIGHT, '<', 'file2.fasta' or die "Can't open file2: $!";
open my $OUT,   '>', 'file3.fasta' or die "Cannot write: $!";

my @left;
while (<$LEFT>) {
    chomp;
    push @left, [ split /\t/ ];
}

while (<$RIGHT>) {
    chomp;
    my ($id, $seq) = split /\t/;
    $id =~ s/</_/;
    print {$OUT} "$_->[0]$id\t$_->[1]$seq\n" for @left;
}
close $OUT or die "Cannot close: $!";
```

Comment: thank you so much! There is still 1 minor glitch. The second '>' is not replaced by a '_' in spite of the s/>/_/; What could be the reason?

Comment: Found it, there's a '<' in stead of a '>', I looked over it. Thanks again!